# Connecting to AmazonMQ (ActiveMQ) broker from .NET using Apache.NMS.AMQP

Tags: .net, activemq-classic, amqp, amazon-mq, apache-nms

I am having trouble connecting to my AmazonMQ broker using Apache.NMS.AMQP client ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp)).

I have AmazonMQ broker up and running and I can connect to broker console.
In my .NET project I have installed Apache.NMQ.AMQP NuGet (v1.8.0) which should be used to connect to ActiveMQ brokers over AMQP.

According to AWS console for Amazon MQ this is the brokers AMQP endpoint, notice `amqp+ssl` schema:

```
amqp+ssl://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671
```

This code snippet is used to connect to broker:

```
var endpoint = "amqp+ssl://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671";
var connectionFactory = new NmsConnectionFactory(endpoint);
var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection("myTestUserName", "myTestPassword");

connection.Start();
```

When using above specified code snippet and broker URL I get following exception when calling `connection.Start()` method: `Apache.NMS.NMSException: Failed to create Provider instance for amqp+ssl`

After some research I've realised that broker should be configured for `amqp+ssl` transport connector which I've tried according to [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/amqp) for AMQP. So I have tried adding following XML to broker configuration:

```
<broker>
    <!-- some other configuration entries -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <transportConnector name="amqp+ssl" uri="amqp+ssl://localhost:5671"/>
    </transportConnectors>
    <!-- some other configuration entries -->
</broker>
```

When trying to save edited configuration AWS presents me the following message:

```
The specified XML configuration data is invalid: cvc-attribute.3: 
The value 'amqp+ssl' of attribute 'name' on element 'transportConnector' is not valid with respect to its type,
'protocol'. and cvc-enumeration-valid: 
Value 'amqp+ssl' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[openwire]'. 
It must be a value from the enumeration.
```

Which, I suppose, means that only 'openwire' transport connector is allowed to be specified in configiration.

The next solution that I've tried is changing broker URL to use `amqp` schema so I got following:

```
var endpoint = "amqp://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5672";
```

instead of

```
var endpoint = "amqp+ssl://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671";
```

which also threw me an exception when calling `connection.Start()` with following message:

```
Apache.NMS.NMSException: 
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

Is there any way to connect to Amazon managed ActiveMQ broker using AMQP protocol and .NET and if there is what am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same scenario in java, mine got resolved by replacing "amqp+ssl" with 
"amqps":

```
var endpoint = "amqps://*my-broker-url*.amazonaws.com:5671";
```

Comment: This has solved my issue.

Reference to documentation where amqps schema is listed
https://github.com/apache/activemq-nms-amqp/blob/master/docs/configuration.md